# Launching the Google Drive sharing dialog in an app. What should be the APP_ID value?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm following [this article](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing#launching_the_google_drive_sharing_dialog_in_your_app), trying to add a sharing dialog in a web app.

I got the button working in opening the modal popup, but it just prints this error in the console:

```
Refused to display 'https://drive.google.com/share?id=SOME_LONG_ID&foreignService=explorer&shareService=explorer&shareProtocolVersion=2&command=init&subapp=10&popupWindowsEnabled=true&shareUiType=default&rand=1386925457304&theme=2&client=postMessage&appId=MY_APP_ID&embedOrigin=http%3A%2F%2Fmy_app.appspot.com'
in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

And the modal itself just shows the message **"Sorry, sharing is unavailable at this time. Please try again later."**

For the checklist at the bottom of the article:

- The user is signed in to Google **True**
- The user has installed your app **False** How do I ask them to install?
- The URL of the page that launches the dialog must have the same origin as the Open URL registered for the app. **True**

So I have 2 questions:

1. How do I ask them to install my app? It's supposed to be a web app, where there's 1 button to select Drive files via the [Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) (which is now working), and then another button which will sow this Drive sharing dialog to set the permissions of the selected files. There's no need for installation. Will it work for this setup?
2. What should be the value for the `APP_ID`? I'm guessing it's the ID in the "Drive SDK" section of the Cloud Console? The console is so confusing and there's so many values for keys, ids, etc. that I have no idea which to use. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YccsR.png) of what I mean by the ID and what I'm trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

(1) **Installing** means you have to get the user to accept the *drive.install* scope - [instructions here](https://developers.google.com/drive/install).  This will integrate your app with the "open with" menu in Google Drive. But before that can work you will need to tell the Google Cloud Console what url to go to when the user clicks "open" - [more instructions](https://developers.google.com/drive/enable-sdk).  In your case, since you don't actually want to allow the user to open files from Drive you won't be defining any file types, so in reality there won't actually be any visible integration with Drive.

Note that the share dialog will only work on the one page which has the url you specify as the target for "open" (the instructions say this and from experience it seems to be true).

(2) **Client ID** You can find this in the Google Cloud Console - see above. Mine is a 12 digit number, so yours will probably be too.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.  The iFrame error shows up when you call setItemIds if your app_id is wrong.  No idea why.  Anyway, it started working for me when I used the right app_id -- the one that shows up like in your screenshot.